# smoothstate.js toggle and toggleClass not working

Tags: jquery, smoothstate.js

I'm using some basic toggle and toggleClass function in mu jQuery code but it doesn't work properly when using smoothstate.js, any idea why ?

$('.filters-open').click(function() {

```
$(this).toggle()
$('#filters-close').toggle()
$('#filters-container').toggle()
```

})